# Auto add more widget (icon) on home screen android

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have some images as icons. When my app run, I want these images auto adding on home screen android. If number of pages of home screen not enough, it auto add new page. How to make this? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not auto-add widgets to the home screen. The platform expressly prevents you from doing that.